# Ajax with twig, how it works?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

From my controller I send several parameters in my html.twig, then I want to make a AJAX request like this one :

```js
{% if text is defined %}
    var text = {{ text }};
    var sender = {{ sender }};
    var date_send = {{ date_send|date('d/m/Y') }};
    var mess_type = {{ mess_type }};
    var to = {{ to }};

    $.post('send.php', {text:text, sender:sender, date_send:date_send, mess_type:mess_type, to:to}, function(data)
    {
        $('#Map').text(data);
    });
{% endif %}
```

SO when I do that, I have this error :

```
POST http://localhost:8000/send.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

My send.php is where my html.twig is. I just have an echo "hi" in my `send.php` for testing, but it does not display anything.

I also tried to put a send function in my controller :

```js
/**
* @Route("/send.php", name="send")
*/
public function send(Request $request) {
    dump("hi");
    echo "send";
    return null;
}
```

And I replace `'send.php'` by `{{path('send.php')}}` inside my `html.twig` (inside `$.post()`).
I know I can't return null, but It does not display my dump. And I have this error :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/send" as such route does not exist.")
```

And it does not get me to `/send.php`. I don't know what can I miss, I didn't find any solution on google. Thank for your help.

Comment: An argument in `path` method should be route name, so in your case it should be `send`.

Comment: I also tried with `send` but I still have this error : `jquery-1.11.3.js:9664 POST http://localhost:8000/send 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: If you get 500 and can't read the error message, then look into logs. There you should find answer.

Comment: this error is what I have inside my log, but symfony does not show me any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A controller's method should return a Response object so try this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/send.php", name="send")
 */
public function send(Request $request)
{
    return new Response('send');
}
```

The twig path function need the route name instead of the path, so try the following:

```
{{path('send')}}
```

Hope this help

NB: I order to identify the real error message, try put the url in the browser and see what happen

Comment: It works well thanks, but how do I use my parameters inside my send function that I sent? And my dump("hi") does not show anything